# Connect USB device to a ceiling light

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, socket

I have a single bulb pendant ceiling light in a funky shade and I'd like to run some led strip lights around the shade.

I've seen this: https://www.olenstechnology.com/product/lampchamp/

Which would work in concept but seems to be a bit big and more than really needed.

Is there a way to wire in a USB socket into the lamp power? Could I dismantle a wall socket USB (like this: [USB wall socket](https://www.directelectrical.co.uk/products/Switches+%26+Sockets/White+Plastic/Nexus+900+Square+White+Plastic+2+Gang+Socket+13A+with+2+x+USB+3.1A/731059500?gclid=Cj0KCQiAl8rQBRDrARIsAEW_To87VIkOiZYRTprDJnVHjbRx0gtgClW7MtamYOZa_D24uy_5G_jTBsAaArGVEALw_wcB)) and hook it into the ceiling wiring?

Or are there any better / dedicated mains to USB socket devices out there?

Comment: you can get socket-to-plug adapter for ~$2, then a small USB wall charger. you can also get socket adapters that have another socket and two plugs.

Comment: @dandavis are you talking E27 sockets? Or wall sockets? As I do not need or want a wall socket in the ceiling! ;-)

Comment: i mean something flush [like this](http://www.acehardware.com/product/index.jsp?productId=29258596) into which you pop [a small USB adapter like this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/1A-Mini-USB-1-Port-Wall-Home-Travel-AC-Charger-Adapter-US-Plug-For-Smart-Phone/292229790911) giving you safe USB in-ceiling without wiring. afaik, there's no direct adapter from E27  to USB, but let me know if you find one.

Comment: Ah, I see... Bit then I lose the actual E27 bulb... But maybe there's a splitter for it?

Comment: yeah, [one like this](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Project-Source-660-Watt-Ivory-Medium-Light-Socket-Adapter/3774299), but that's a bit bulkier, and might need [a side-exiting USB adapter](https://www.ebay.com/itm/US-Home-Travil-Wall-Micro-USB-Adapter-Cable-Charger-for-Smartphone-Tablet-PC/232104924841) to keep it in the fixture.

Comment: @dandavis your comment should be added as an answer, I was thinking of similar. It would be code legal and not as much of a mickey mouse as some things I have replaced for DIY folks.+

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a non-hokeydokey way to mix mains powered E27 and LED strips in the same fixture, and USB only makes it worse.  Here's what I'd do.

### Convert the whole works to 12V or 24V DC

For the LED strips, you use any of the *literally thousands* of 12V LED strips readily available for $7 per 5 meters, all over ebay and amazon, or hundreds of 24V LED strips.

For the E27 screw-in bulb, you use 12-24V LED bulbs intended for RVs.  Most of them work on both 12V and 24V.

If it has a lamp cord and plugs in, just put a 12v or 24v "wall wart" power supply on the end of the lamp cord.  If you have space up in the lamp,  you could also use a modular power supply such as those made by Meanwell.

This will not be dimmable.  But for the LED strips, 12/24V dimming and RGB controllers are readily available and could be tucked up inside the lamp.  They use a wireless remote.  This would work for the LED strips not the screw-in.

If someone screws in a 120V bulb into the socket, it just won't work.